# Changing layouts in SWING

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have written a program with flow layout, in Java, using Swing Framework. How do I change it to use group layout?

Comment: "A program"? What language, OS, Framework or API?

Comment: @Dour: Java and Swing, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to start with the [Java Tutorials on GroupLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).